# Flask SQLAlchemy reverse inclusion a many to many query

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm quite new to SQLAlchemy.
For this project I'm using flask and sqlalchemy.

One of the routes I need is to make is to add users to a certain group. So I need to create a list of users which are not included in this group.

I made an SQL statement and tried it in my database, which gives me the result I need, I'm just not good at converting this into SQLAlchemy

`select id, email from users where id not in ( select user_id from user_group where group_id = 1);`

my models look like this

```
UserGroup = db.Table(
    "user_group",
    db.Model.metadata,
    db.Column("user_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("users.id")),
    db.Column("group_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("groups.id")),
)
    
class Group(db.Model, RestrictionsMixin):
    __tablename__ = "groups"
    __versioned__ = {}
    __restrictions__ = {}

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False, unique=True)

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    __versioned__ = {}

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(250), unique=True, nullable=False)
    _password = db.Column(db.LargeBinary(60), nullable=False)
    authenticated = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=True, nullable=False)
    email_confirmation_sent_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True)
    email_confirmed = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=True, default=False)
    email_confirmed_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True)
    registered_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True)
    last_logged_in = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True)

    groups = db.relationship("Group", secondary="user_group", backref="users")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
user_group_subquery = (
    db.session.query(UserGroup.c.user_id).filter(UserGroup.c.group_id == 1).subquery()
)
db.session.query(User.id, User.email).filter(~User.id.in_(user_group_subquery))
```

[The tilde (`~`) returns the negation of a clause](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.not_).

Comment: Thanks Bas, I've changed my solution to yours. For the last few days I have been going through the whole SQLAlchemy documentation to learn every aspect of it. I found a little work around  which was  basically using `db.session.query(User).from_statement(text("select * from users where id not in (select user_id from user_group where group_id = :group)") ).params(group=id).all()` Still have a bit of docs to go through. Thanks for your solution.